# Comment traduire « the pilots had to raise their voices, audibly, to be heard above [...] » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, prépositions, adverbes, formulation-idiomatique

> **The pilots had to raise their voices, [audibly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/audible), to be heard
> above** [*the unholy [tattoo](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/tattoo) of this hail which was [buckshotting](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buckshot)
> the airplaine*. (voir [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/47178/26366) pour cette partie)] ([source](https://youtu.be/5CU5r27BSbs?t=346))

Les pilotes ont dû parler plus fort, [*de manière à être entendu*], afin d'être entendus [[*préposition impliquant de dépasser ce qui suit*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/above)]...

- Comment traduit-on le segment « The pilots had to raise their voices, audibly, to be heard above » quelque chose ? Peut-on dire *hausser la voix* sans connotation (autorité, colère) vu le contexte ; comment choisit-on l'adverbe pour résoudre ce qui à première vue ressemble un peu à une redondance lexicale (*entendu*) ; quelle préposition choisit-on pour imbriquer ce qui va suivre ?

Comment: This sentence is just not very good in English. Generally, *you raise your voice so you can be heard**.  You don't generally raise your voices "audibly". Les pilotes ont été obligé de parler bien plus fort pour se faire entendre au dessus du vacarme etc.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not here to correct [native speakers](https://youtu.be/5CU5r27BSbs?t=350) (maybe from the South), but to find an answer to my question with the quote as is. Se faire entendre _au-dessus_ ? Imho that feels like a loan construction, using that preposition doesn't sound right to me at all. If it were basic stuff I wouldn't ask.

Comment: Quand la voix doit passer au-dessus du bruit ambiant. https://www.homeovox.fr/la-voix-dans-tous-ses-etats/quand-la-voix-doit-passer-au-dessus-du-bruit-ambiant Do you accept that?

Comment: Nothing could be more French than this: L'association "Les riverains de la Butte-aux-Vailles" a été créée dans les années 1990 en réponse à la multiplication des nuisances engendrées par les nombreuses ouvertures de bars et de restaurants dans ce quartier de Paris. Face à l'ampleur des problèmes liés au bruit en particulier, des habitants ont décidé de constituer une association **pour faire entendre leurs voix au dessus du brouhaha des terrasses de cafés**. https://www.bruit.fr/bruits-de-voisinage/bruits-de-voisinage Alors, "au dessus du vacarme infernal" passe très bien, à mon avis.

Comment: Ok, that is spoken English, with all the usual warts. It is not written speech but it is what I said. It is not southern English, It is just spoken, but my rewrite is exactly what he said, cleaned up to make it translateable.

Comment: I already explained that phrasing re spoken language and I don't feel like doing any more work on this., Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Il me semble qu'***audibly*** a simplement été utilisé ici pour indiquer que l'intensification de la puissance sonore était suffisamment importante pour être bien "audible" (perçue).

Je traduirais donc le début de cette phrase par:

> Les pilotes ont dû élever la voix, **très nettement**, afin d'être entendus [...]

On pourrait aussi utiliser d'autres adverbes comme **distinctement**, **significativement**, etc.

Comment: _Distinctement_ +1. Larousse en ligne suggère ça d'ailleurs.

Answer (score 0):

- les pilotes ont dû hausser la voix pour se faire entendre dans le bruit de …

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hausser)) α) [Le compl. désigne une production sonore] Augmenter l'intensité (d'un son). Synon. élever; anton. baisser.
> ♦ Le petit bruit continuait toujours et Isabelle, ne ménageant plus rien, haussait la voix pour le couvrir (Gautier, Fracasse,1863, p. 403).
> ♦ Leurs cris farouches couvraient la voix du chanteur qui vainement haussait sur l'assemblée la clameur harmonieuse de sa bouche et de sa lyre (A. France, Clio,1900, p. 34).

[se faire entendre dans le bruit de](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22faire%20entendre%20dans%20le%20bruit%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis À mon avis, l'usage figuré  de l'expression « raise one's voice » dans le sens de « faire entendre son opinion » est fort, et donc « audibly » n'est qu'une précision, dont on peut se passer en français. (voir cette page: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22raise%20their%20voice%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

Comment: Je t'invite à verser ça à ta réponse quand le coeur t'en dira. Je ne suis pas d'accord dans le sens où dans la vidéo, tu vois le locuteur bien appuyer là-dessus donc pour moi c'est significatif à défaut peut-être d'être important.