# Comment traduire « [...] the unholy tattoo of this hail which was buckshotting the airplane » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

[image]
<sup><sup>Image extraite de la source sur youtube pour illustrer le propos : « A Dangerous Storm & Two Failed Engines! | Southern Storm | Mayday: Air Disaster »</sup></sup>

> [The pilots had to raise their voices, [audibly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/audible), to be heard
> above (voir [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/47177/26366) pour cette partie)] ***the [unholy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unholy) [tattoo](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/tattoo)<sup>1</sup> of this hail which was [buckshotting](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buckshot)
> the airplane*.** ([source](https://youtu.be/5CU5r27BSbs?t=346))

---

> ...[***l'aspect rythmique du bruit***] [***unholy***] **de la grêle
> qui [***analogie avec un type de tir***] le fuselage/l'avion.**

- Comment traduit/transpose-t-on le segment « the unholy tattoo of this hail which
  was buckshotting the airplane » en fonction du contexte et du style ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> En plus de [*Merriam Learners*](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/tattoo) que j'utilise, voir aussi [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tattoo), [*American Heritage*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tattoo), [*Etymonline*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=tattoo) et [*OED1*](https://archive.org/details/oed9barch/page/n523/mode/1up).</sub>

Comment: Je comprends l'analogie entre la grêle et une décharge de chevrotine (buckshot), mais le tatouage, je ne comprends pas : la grêle est-elle censée laisser un dessin sur l'avion?

Comment: @XouDo Non, voir le sens 3 du lien, ce n'est pas un truc graphique, c'est « a rapid rhythmic beat » : _The rain was beating a tattoo on the roof_.

Comment: @XouDo https://www.yourdictionary.com/tattooing

Comment: In English, the metaphor is slightly mixed up. They are trying to say that the **the hail made an unholy racket, like buckshot tattooing the plane**.   "unholy" is a *slang* word: the kids were making an unholy racket. That is: a lot of noise.

Comment: Les pilotes ont été obligé de parler bien plus fort pour se faire entendre au dessus du vacarme infernal provoqué par la grèle contre l'avion comme celui d'un tatouage par la chévrotine.

Comment: @Lambie Your translation doesn't feel idiomatic to me at all. Who gets tattoed by a buckshot I mean, no.

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis "Who gets tattoed by a buckshot"? What do you mean by that? First, there is no "a buckshot". The hail was tattooing the plane like buckshot. [airplane, not airplaine, by the way. No doubt about that.

Comment: Mais les pilotes doivent être entendus « above » un truc, serait-on entendu « au-dessus » d'un tatouage causé par des plombs ?? Ou plutôt « au-dessus » d'un bruit rythmique, ce n'est pas la même chose ? @Lambie p.s. I mean, you are aware the _a rapid rhythmic beat_  meaning is in the dictionary, I'm not making this up: https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/tattoo see meaning 3. Does the example _The rain was beating a tattoo on the roof_ support your construction? If you're saying the speaker isn't using that please expand on that in an answer.

Comment: You are not getting the English.,  I'm not going to argue with you about the English. Can't you see thee problem we are having here?

Comment: Oh but I am. You're not, because _beating a tattoo_ in  _The rain was beating a tattoo on the roof_ that tattoo refers to « signal calling soldiers or sailors to quarters at night » (Etymonline: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=tattoo). From _tap to_. You don't even know you own language. @Lambie

Comment: What happened to the video? If I had know that from the start.

Comment: The video is here, I was trying to clean up comments: https://youtu.be/5CU5r27BSbs?t=350 My question properly transcribes the entire sentence from start to finish.

Answer (score 5):

Il semble que le sens sonore de tattoo ne vient pas de la machine du tatoueur :
https://www.etymonline.com/word/tattoo

> (...)  In English, transferred sense of "drumbeat" is recorded from 1755

Et apparemment, il y a bien un sens "informel" pour *unholy* pouvant s'appliquer à un bruit : https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/unholy

> unholy adjective (UNPLEASANT)
>
> [ before noun ] informal
>
> extremely unpleasant:
> an **unholy** mess/row/**noise**

---

Sachant cela, voici les phrases que je propose dans ce contexte :

> (...) pour réussir à couvrir le tambourinage de tous les diables de la grêle qui mitraillait la carlingue.

ou (par analogie au roulement de tambour et au [feu roulant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/feu_roulant)) :

> (...) pour se faire entendre malgré le roulement infernal de la grêle mitraillant la carlingue de l'avion.

ou encore, une variante moins fidèle à la phrase originale :

> (...) pour couvrir le vacarme insensé de la grêle dont les rafales giflaient sans cesse le fuselage.

Comment: +1 pour infernal : meilleure traduction de *unholy* ici. Et oui, *tattoo* c'est un bruit qui n'a rien à voir avec le tatoueur. Deux racines différentes (racine germanique pour l'un polynésienne pour l'autre).

Comment: @None C'est moi qui a dit infernal pour unholy.

Comment: @Lambie et oui!

Answer (score 4):

> Les pilotes ont dû élever la voix, distinctement, afin de pouvoir être entendus malgré le fracas de la grêle qui [mitraillait](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/47180/1109) le fuselage.

Avec un registre plus argotique :

> Les pilotes ont dû brailler grave pour se faire entendre malgré le raffut de la grêle qui mitraillait le zinc façon marteau-piqueur.

De nouvelles propositions qui incluent deux interprétations possibles du mot *tatoo*, la deuxième étant nettement plus vraisemblable.

> Les pilotes s'époumonaient pour se faire entendre malgré la grêle qui crépitait sur le fuselage avec un bruit de machine à tatouer.

> Les pilotes s'égosillaient pour se faire entendre malgré la grêle qui martelait le fuselage comme les baguettes d'un tambour.

Comment: Mais le monsieur ne parle pas du tout en argot. mittrailer is a rattatat sound. or even machine gunning, which is way over the top here.

Comment: @Lambie Je n'ai aucune idée du registre de la phrase en anglais, mais comme tu as écrit dans un commentaire que *unholy* était de l'argot, j'ai ajouté cette variante. Je ne l'impose pas. Le bruit de la grêle sur la carlingue d'un avion me semble pouvoir être comparé à un mitraillage.

Comment: In English, I associate *tattoo* with *rapid* drumming (not necessarily loud or soft) ... I think *un mitraillage* is an excellent translation. En anglais, j'associe *a tattoo* avec *un tambourinage rapide*... je crois que *mitraillage* est une très bonne traduction.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, I wasn't aware of this meaning but it seems indeed to better fit the context.

Comment: @PeterShor mitraillage is machine gunning. Too strong.

Comment: @Lambie A *mitraillage* is not necessarily that strong. It is obviously a figurative usage and can more relate to the frequency than the force, like the *photographes qui mitraillent la montée des marches*.

Comment: Aussi d'accord pour mitraillage, ça correspond tout à fait au sens donné dans l'OED pour *tatoo*: "A beating or pulsation as of a drum; the action of beating, thumping, or **rapping continuously upon something**".

Comment: Même si certains termes familiers peuvent être argotiques, ce n'est pas le cas pour [unholy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unholy)* n'est pas un terme argotique, juste familier. L'OED non plus ne le signale pas comme argotique.

Comment: et *buckshotting* est aussi familier, mais pas argotique.

Answer (score 1):

- les impossibles  claquements par centaines de cette grêle qui mitraillait l'avion

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/claquer)) **claquer** I.− Emploi intrans.A.− Produire un bruit sec et éclatant

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/claquement)) **claquement** A.− Action de claquer; le son bref qui en résulte. Le claquement d'une porte, d'un fouet; des claquements de dents, de langue, de mains (

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/impossible)) **impossible** − P. hyperb. Dont la réalité ou le déroulement sont difficilement supportables. Synon. intolérable.Mais en moins de trois jours la vie devint impossible! (Vercel, Cap. Conan,1934, p. 88).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mitrailler)) **mitrailler** C. − P. anal. Mitrailler qqn/qqc.de qqc.
> 1 [Le compl. indir. désigne un inanimé concr.: fleurs, confettis] Lancer des projectiles en grand nombre sur quelqu'un/quelque chose.
> ♦ Dans les voitures on s'appelle, on se reconnaît, on se mitraille avec des roses. Un char plein de jolies femmes vêtues de rouge comme des diables, attire et séduit les yeux.  (Maupass.,Contes et nouv.,t.1, Rose, 1884, p.924)

Comment: _Mitrailler, impossible_. +1

Answer (score 1):

> ...le [tapage](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tapage) [invraisemblable](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/unholy/621238)/[inouï](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/inou%C3%AF) (!) de la grêle qui
> s'abattait sur l'avion comme *une pluie de balles*/autant de
> *[volées](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vol%C3%A9e) de [mitraille](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mitraille)*<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Ces formulations sont inspirées de phrases chez Verne (« Le canon du gaillard d'avant partit, criblant les flots tranquilles d'une volée de mitraille », Verne, *Enf. Cap. Grant*, t. 3, 1868, p. 197) et Zola (« Une briqueterie était là, offrant un refuge. De l'autre côté, une pluie de balles en criblait les murs », Zola, *Débâcle*, 1892, p. 220) avec le verbe « [cribler](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cribler) » (TLFi)...</sub>

Comment: Comparer avec : «...du tatouage impie (et ce n'était pas un simple battement de tatouage du diable [hahaha petit ajout _no mere beating of the devil's tattoo_, ou sans _battement_ si j'enlève _of_, donc ignoré]) de cette grêle qui mitraillait l'avion. » (DeepL)

Answer (score -6):

Ok, voici le discours du type qui parle **avec tous les traits que l'on trouve dans le langage parlé.**

Il dit la phrase suivante et moi **en tant qu'interprète** de suis obligée de faire avec:

- The pilots had to raise their voices, audibly, to be heard above] the unholy tattoo of this hail which was buckshotting the airplane.
- Les pilotes étaient obligés de parler très fort, pour que cela soit audible, en dessus du bruit du tatouage infernal de cette grêle qui se heurtait comme de la chevrotine contre l'avion.

Comment: Non, pas le tattoo avec l'encre, le tattoo de tambouriner. [See dictionary.](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tattoo)

Comment: @PeterShor That is BrE, according to that dictionary. The speaker appears to me American.

Comment: [it doesn't matter.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tattoo)

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, a tattoo makes noise. tambouriner is much softer.

Comment: tambouriner is throbbing or drumming, here he is clearly talking about noise. Tattooing is noisy. So, my translation is not inaccurate.

Comment: In English, *tattooing **is** drumming*.  And not necessarily loud drumming (although it clearly is in this case). [See the dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tattoo). The OP is clearly not talking about tattoo machines.

Comment: I understand what the dictionary says. And if you say tambour, tambouriner, the sound is dull (sourd). I think it's like the sound of tattooing. Ergo, that's what I  said what I did. Plus, it's unholy, so definitely noisy. Like tattooing.

Comment: [Discussion in chat about suggested improvements to the answer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128721/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lambie).

Comment: _Tattoo machine_ (1 hour): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTr0YeaMWhk ; Just your typical _hail_ hitting windows (10 hours): https://youtu.be/4C2IQDXPqZQ ; _Big hail_ hitting a car: https://youtu.be/S9DY0hcnoKQ. See also the source material (was in the comments, added to Q.).