# « Cribler » sans « percer » avec « ...qui s'abattait sur l'avion comme une pluie de balles/autant de volées de mitraille » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, syntaxe, formulation

> ...le tapage invraisemblable de la grêle qui *s'abattait* sur
> l'avion comme une pluie de balles/autant de volées de mitraille.

Pense-t-on qu'il est possible de formuler cette phrase avec le verbe [*cribler*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cribler) plutôt que le pronominal *s'abattre* avec de tels compléments mais sans signifier que l'on *perce* le fuselage (d'un avion) comme tel, à la manière de *cribler de coups* tout en restant naturel : peut-on expliquer ? Quelle(s) modification(s) doit-on apporter à la phrase si c'est le cas ?

Comment: This was the spoken English sentence of this aviation journalist, right? https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/47178/comment-traduire-the-unholy-tattoo-of-this-hail-which-was-buckshotting-t/47190#47190//The pilots had to raise their voices, audibly, to be heard above the unholy tattoo of this hail which was buckshotting the airplane.

Answer (score -1):

Vu le sens du verbe considéré que donne le TLFi, en particulier ces deux variantes,

- « 1. Percer une personne ou une chose en plusieurs endroits »,
- « 2. Tacheter en beaucoup d'endroits. »,

on se rend compte qu'il est question soit de percer quelque chose  soit de  traces de la sorte appelée « tâche » ;  un examen de la littérature montre que ce couple de définitions est bien moins qu'idéal.  Il s'agit non pas du concept assez particulier de « tâche » mais de celui de « trace », et en plus ces traces peuvent  être soit  plus ou moins permanentes (voire partie **I** ci-dessous) soit des traces d'une durée de vie très courte (voire **II**).  Pour finir, n'est pas exclu le cas où la notion de trace s'estompe largement (voire **III**), ou devient tout à fait abstraite (voire **IV**). Cela aboutit finalement à une notion abstraite de « cribler » dans laquelle il n'est  plus question de trace mais où seule subsiste l'idée d'un grand nombre d'occurrences (**V**).

Les parties de texte relevées ci-dessous montrent cela ; on peut les vérifier sur [cette page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22criblait%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=9OgeYbHzMaGelwSBp42AAg&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwixvYaxnr7yAhUhz4UKHYFTAyA4ZBDy0wN6BAgBEEA&biw=1280&bih=671&dpr=1.5) et sur [celle-ci](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22criblait%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=qO0eYduOFIzeaumojPgH&start=100&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjbgvfuor7yAhUMrxoKHWkUA38Q8tMDegQIARBB&biw=1280&bih=671&dpr=1.5) si plus ample information est nécessaire.

**I**

1/ La roséole [tâches rosées], extrêmement abondante , criblait le tronc , les membres et la face

2/ Mais, comme la plupart du temps les oiseaux ne venaient pas, il criblait les branches de son plomb. Ses persécuteurs ne s'épouvantaient pas du bruit,

3/ À mesure qu'ils se rapprochaient, cependant, Lyrna s'aperçut qu'une multitude de plates-formes et de croisées troglodytes la criblait de toutes parts.

4/ On parlait bas , une fine pluie d'automne criblait les feuilles . Le petit avait froid , elle lui jetait dessus la moitié de sa grande mante

5/ Un millier d'étoiles criblait le ciel tandis que la lune gelée regardait le château comme l'œil d'un immense dragon.

6/ C'était un feu pesant qui criblait ces misérables de mille grêlons. La clameur fut déchirante. Ils s'enfuirent pêle-mêle, jetant le madrier sur les cadavres

7/ La pluie criblait la boue jusqu'à former un ruisseau au milieu de la chaussée.

8/ Une fois seule, elle façonna le mouchoir en forme de rose, pendant que la pluie criblait la fenêtre.

9/ Tout comme le chuintement continu qui l'accompagnait et qui lui criblait le visage.

10/ La pluie avait redoublé d'intensité et criblait la surface de l'eau de milliers de petits cratères.

11/ La rouille criblait certains des panneaux.

12/ Le jeune prêtre avançait entre les barres d'immeubles de Rossville Street, à travers un brouillard lacrymogène qu'un soleil diffus criblait de rais blancs

**II**

1/  De son éclat jaune pâle, elle léchait la roche noire des falaises et criblait de diamants la surface irisée du Glacier.

2/  Un soleil idéal criblait ses cheveux de rayons d'or , sa robe avait des transparences d'émeraude , ses épaules scintillaient comme du marbre de Paros

3/ Les arbres nus brodaient le rivage de leurs linéaments noirs et rigides , et la lune criblait l'eau doucement mouvante , la pailletait d'argent en fusion

4/ Le tonnerre explosait à mes oreilles, la grêle criblait nos armes d'étincelles et la foudre nous poursuivait de ses éclairs sans nombre.

**III**

1/  Le soleil qui le criblait ne faisait que l'aiguillonner encore ;

2/ Le déconcertant soleil de midi qui le criblait de ses rayons semblait se rire de ses efforts infructueux.

**IV**

1/ et il attaquait son adversaire avec une fureur fanatique , le criblait de chocs violens et déconcertait par sa fougue tous ses mouvemens

2/ mais Francesco , en proie à une rage frénétique , s'était jeté sur lui , le criblait de coups , et telle fut son aveugle fureur

3/ serrait Charlie à l'étouffer, lui criblait la figure de baisers remercieurs, disait en riant nerveusement: —Un grand garçon! un grand garçon!

**V**

1/ On ne pouvait pardonner à un homme qui, avec une franchise souriante, criblait son interlocuteur de questions et d'objections dont

2/ Le cri des mouettes survolait des grincements de poulies, des battements de moteurs, criblait le taffetas du ressac et le déchirait.

3/  La voix jurait et tempêtait avec violence : elle criblait d'une bordée de jurons la paix solennelle de la haie. Elle commença par m'appeler : « Cochon !

***CONCLUSION***

Je crois que l'enseignement que l'on tire de cette aperçu de la littérature est clair, et qu'il n'y a pas à hésiter ; si « cribler » semble contribuer l'image la plus parlante l'utiliser ne peut pas introduire d'idée sans réalité, c'est une utilisation prouvée dont le bon sens  dans les cas « **I** », « **II** » et « **IV**  » est indiscutable ; je ne dirais pas de même pour le cas « **III** ». Le cas de l'emploi figuré (**V**) est une autre question.

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Sur les pages indiquées on trouve des quantités d'exemples avec « balle » (de fusil) et autres projectiles de cette sorte ; il ne sont pas inclus parce que jugés banaux. Les (volées de) balles contre un mur de pierre ou un gros blindage ne percent rien, elles laissent seulement des impacts, et il n'y a pas que des hommes sur un champs de bataille. Personnellement, qu'il s'agisse de « abattre » ou de « cribler » je n'utiliserais pas « autant » : il n'y a pas, par exemple « des bourrasques de grêle », ce qui seul  justifierait ce mot à cet endroit selon   (1/3)

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis  mon optique de son usage, cela au vu de l'addition de « volées » (un pluriel) {voir TLFi — I.− Adv. de compar. exprimant en phrase compar., explicite ou implicite, l'égalité de deux procès, quant à leur intensité, **leur quantité** ou leur valeur. C.− Loc. Être autant de + subst. − Rem. Cette loc. insiste partic. sur l'identité, l'équivalence des deux procès mis en corrélation, puisqu'en réalité il s'agit d'une même chose vue sous deux angles différents (cf. l'expr. suivante). − (Être) comme autant : ♦ En un instant, mille pensées vives et douloureuses (2/3)

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis  me piquèrent comme autant de dards.}. Autrement, je ne changerais rien. (3/3)

Comment: Tu conserverais même la préposition _sur_ ? Je comprends ce que tu expliques. Mais des balles ne peuvent percer un mur de pierre parce que c'est un mur de pierre justement, pas un mince fuselage. La différence entre la pluie et autant de volées, c'est que _autant_ signifie _beaucoup de_ et c'est requis parce que la grêle est constante et une _volée_, non, comme le _buckshot_. La pluie, elle, est constante, comme la grêle. En fait à mon avis ta réponse aurait pu se passer de tous ces exemples et expliquer exactement ce qui se trouve dans ton commentaire ça aurait été bien plus clair pour moi.

Comment: Au contraire ce sont des emplois avec les balles etc. mais employés en comparaison, qui sont pertinents à mon avis. On salue par ailleurs l'effort. Merci.

Comment: @LPH  Attention, le pluriel de **banal** est **banals**, pas **banaux**.

Comment: @jlliagre Alors « -aux » est probablement utilisé seulement pour le mot du concept historique.

Comment: Oui, c'est bien ça.